# Which bytes of the file remain mapped?

Tags: linux, paging

A file is mapped with the the system call:

```
mmap(65536, 32768, READ, FLAGS, fd, 0)
```

Pages are 8 KB, so 4 pages worth of the file were mapped (32768/8k = 4 pages). Then the following call is carried out:

```
munmap(65536, 8192)
```

Which removes the specified part of the memory map. Which bytes of the file remain mapped? The answer key says that pages 2 and 3 remain, so only bytes 16384 through 32767 remain; however, I'm not sure this is right. Since the `len` argument (second arg) of the `munmap` command is 8192 byes, shouldn't only page 0 be removed, leaving bytes 8192 through 32767?

Comment: Your logic seems right to me. Their answer would be correct if the `munmap` size were `8193`.

Comment: @duskwuff According to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/munmap.html, `addr` has to be a multiple of the page size, but it doesn't say anything about `len`.

Comment: @Barmar My mistake. Misread the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Both you and the answer key are wrong, but in different ways.

Memory pages on most systems are 4 KB (4096 bytes), not 8 KB. I have never heard of a system with 8 KB memory pages.

This makes the entire mapping of 32768 bytes come out to 8 pages. Unmapping the first 8192 bytes (2 pages) would leave the remaining 6 pages (2 through 8) in place.